# Is this technical question with a political aspect on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently on the main meta [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364738/asking-a-technical-question-with-a-political-aspect?noredirect=1#comment1217381_364738) came up:

> I think most of you have heard of the recent unrest in Israel/Palestinian territory. Arabs have viewed Facebook as a biased social media platform that favors Israeli posts. Therefore, they've started giving a one-star rating for the Facebook app on PlayStore, which caused the FaceBook rating to plummet to 2 from 4.5
>
> So,I'd like to ask a question about the mass downvoting of a certain app and its effects on the technical and business levels.

Would this question be on-topic here if it focused on the political aspect of why that app got negative reviews?

Note: I am asking on behalf of [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/309010/sam-ibraheem) who does not have enough rep to participate here yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would be off-topic because the question as phrased is primarily not about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the [Help Center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

While the Israel-Palestine conflict is in scope, questions asking how that conflict affects *"technical and business"* aspects of a social media app are not.

Of course there is a political aspect that motivates participation in mass downvoting, asking about that might be on-topic. In that case, the question would have to phrased in a way that it doesn't call for speculation.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to ask a question about the mass downvoting of a certain app and its effects on the technical and business levels.

The motives for the people participating in a downvoting campaign are not relevant for the effects on the technical and business levels. So I don't think that this is a question about politics and political processes as defined in the help center.